# How to get different deptnos records based on same empid and name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server: how to get same `empid` and name have different deptno values (more than one deptnos) in SQL Server?

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empcnt]
(
    [empid] [int] NULL,
    [name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [deptno] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[empcnt] ([empid], [name], [deptno]) 
VALUES (1, N'a', 10), (1, N'b', 20),
       (3, N'd', 40), (3, N'd', 40),
       (4, N'e', 59), (3, N'u', 40),
       (5, N'h', 60), (1, N'a', 10),
       (1, N'b', 50)
GO
```

Based on that table, I want output like below:

```
empid | name | deptno
------+------+--------
  1   | b    | 20
  1   | b    | 50
```

I tried like this:

```
select distinct 
    emp.empid, emp.name, emp.deptno 
from 
    empcnt emp  
join 
    (select  
         empid, name, count(*) cnt  
     from 
         empcnt 
     group by 
         empid, name 
     having 
         count(*) > 1) a on emp.EMPID = a.empid
                         and emp.NAME = a.name
```

but this query returns duplicated records with differnt deptnos information, I need only same empid and name have different deptnos information.

Above query is not returning the expected result.

Please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: Why would one employee id have more than one name?  That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

```
select distinct emp.empid,emp.name,emp.deptno 
from empcnt emp  join 
( 
select  empid,name  
  from empcnt 
  group by empid,name 
having count(distinct deptno)>1
)a on emp.EMPID=a.empid
and emp.NAME=a.name
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0122/2).

Aside from joining the tables, you can also use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM empcnt a
WHERE EXISTS
  (
    select  empid,name  
    from empcnt b
    WHERE a.empid = b.empid AND a.name = b.Name
    group by empid,name 
    having count(distinct deptno)>1
  )
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f0122/4).

Comment: Second logic seems to be reliable in terms for performance +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             min(deptno) over (partition by empid) as min_deptno,
             max(deptno) over (partition by empid) as max_deptno
      from empcnt e
     ) e
where min_deptno <> max_deptno;
```

If the same employee id can have more than one name (which seems rather perverse), then include both in the `partition by`:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             min(deptno) over (partition by empid, empname) as min_deptno,
             max(deptno) over (partition by empid, empname) as max_deptno
      from empcnt e
     ) e
where min_deptno <> max_deptno;
```

Comment: i believe the reason why you are being downvoted is because your query does not work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/de5f9/3

Comment: @JohnWoo. . . The query works.  I fail to see what your SQL Fiddle is supposed to prove.

Comment: I was referring to your first query. If you run it against the fiddle, it will return `1 a 50` which the user does want in the original post. However, your second query gives what the user wants.

Answer (score 0):

This is simulation of `count(distinct)` with window functions

```
select
    empid, name, deptno
from (
    select 
        empid, name, deptno
        , cnt = dense_rank() over (partition by empid order by deptno)
        - dense_rank() over (partition by empid, name order by deptno)
    from empcnt
) t
where cnt > 0
```